# Mobile view and storefornt theme not customisation

Tags: wordpress, mobile, view, storefront

Can i get some hints how to fix the issue - Storefront in word-press is not showing the products in 2 columns in a mobile view?

Tried the CSS change
https://wordpress.org/support/topic/2-products-per-row-on-mobile-storefront/

I appreciate the help and support.   I, tried to modify css but no luck  .